# Migrate create_function() which is not supported since PHP 7.2

Tags: php, create-function

I have 'create_function() in my PHP code:

```
function encode_code_in_comment( $source ) { $encoded = preg_replace_callback( '/\[(php|html|javascript|css|nginx|apache|terminal)\](.*?)\[\/\1\]/ims',

    create_function(
        '$matches',
        '$matches[2] = preg_replace(
              array("/^[\r|\n]+/i", "/[\r|\n]+$/i"), "",
              $matches[2]);
              return "<pre class=\"language-" . $matches[1] . "\"><code>" . esc_html( $matches[2] ) . "</code></pre>";'
    ),
    $source );

if ( $encoded ) {
    return $encoded;
} else {
    return $source;
}}
```

I know that there are duplicates threads about the subject, but nevertheless, i'm really struggling to covert this to an anonymous function. How do i rewrite it?

Comment: Have you managed to make an attempt based on the existing explanations you've found? How far did you get? What do you think is different in your code, compared to the examples you've seen?

Comment: By the way, note that `create_function` was only *deprecated* in PHP 7.2 - that means it started giving you advance warning that it would be removed in future. It was actually *removed* in PHP 8.0.

Comment: I didnt got very far, the examples seen in other threads have 2 arguments (args & code) and does not have the "$source" statement in it which i have in my code. I'm sorry if i'm not understanding correctly, i am trying to learn..

Comment: You are correct, it was removed in PHP 8.0

Comment: Thanks, hopefully i'll get an answer from someone... Appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that your code is badly formatted, making it hard to see where the `create_function` call begins and ends; here it is with some more logical linebreaks and indents:

```php
function encode_code_in_comment( $source ) { 
    $encoded = preg_replace_callback( 
        '/\[(php|html|javascript|css|nginx|apache|terminal)\](.*?)\[\/\1\]/ims',

        create_function(
            '$matches',
            '
                $matches[2] = preg_replace(
                    array("/^[\r|\n]+/i", "/[\r|\n]+$/i"),
                    "",
                    $matches[2]
                );
                return "<pre class=\"language-" . $matches[1] . "\"><code>" . esc_html( $matches[2] ) . "</code></pre>";
            '
        ),
        
        $source 
    );

    if ( $encoded ) {
        return $encoded;
    } else {
        return $source;
    }
}
```

From this and [the documentation of `create_function`](https://php.net/create_function), we can see that the created function needs one argument, `$matches`, and to have a body starting `$matches[2] =` and ending `</pre>";`

Looking at [the manual for anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) we see that the new syntax is `function(arguments) { body }`, so instead of:

```
create_function('$matches', ... )
```

you want:

```
function($matches) { ... }
```

and in between, instead of:

```
'
   $matches[2] = ...
   ... 
   ... </pre>";
'
```

you want to just remove the quotes and leave the code:

```
$matches[2] = ...
... 
... </pre>";
```

The body is in single quotes, and there are no escaped single quotes in there, so the code doesn't need any other changes.